# What is the best way to use Guzzle to check if a remote file exists?

Tags: php, guzzle

I would like to use Guzzle to check if a remote file exists.

This is an example of how I am currently checking:

```
/**
 * @return boolean
 */
function exists()
{
    // By default get_headers uses a GET request to fetch the headers.
    // Send a HEAD request instead
    stream_context_set_default(
        array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'HEAD'
            )
        )
    );

    // Get the file headers
    $file_headers = @get_headers($this->file);

    // Check file headers for 404
    if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found')
        return false; // File not available.

    return true; // File is available!
}
```

However, since I'm already using Guzzle elsewhere, I'd think I could make this prettier and more readable.

Am I right in thinking that? How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Have you looked at [the docs](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#sending-requests)? To send a HEAD request you use the `GuzzleHttp\Client::head` method. From there you just need to figure out how to check for 404.

Comment: @quickshiftin Thanks, I did manage to find part of the solution in the docs.

Comment: Nicely done, +1 from me ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did manage to find part of the answer in the docs. [Guzzle - Request Methods](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/http-messages.html?highlight=header#request-methods)

Combined with a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ycombinator/9395033) that has a similar function, that checks for 404 status.

```
/**
 * @return boolean
 */
function exists()
{
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    try {
        $client->head($this->file);
        return true;
    } catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```