# How to check if endpoint is working when using GuzzleHTTP

Tags: php, guzzle

So I am working with `guzzleHttp` and I can get the responses that I am after and catch errors.

The only problem I am having is that if the base URI is wrong, the whole script fails... how can I do some sort of checking to make sure that the endpoint is actually up?

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $url]);
```

Comment: You can check if the `$url` exists, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555661/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-guzzle-to-check-if-a-remote-file-exists

Comment: what about utilizing the response code as returned within the Psr7 response? `$response->getStatusCode()`

Answer (score 1):

You might have many issues with your query, not only that the endpoint is down. Network interface on your server can go down right at the moment of query, DNS can go down, a route to the host might not be available, a connection timeout, etc.

So you definitely should be ready for many issues. I usually catch a general `RequestException` and do something (logging, app specific handling), plus catch specific exceptions if I should handle them differently.

Also, there are many existing patterns (and solutions) for error handling. For example, it's usual to retry a query is an endpoint is unavailable.

```
$stack = HandlerStack::create();
$stack->push(Middleware::retry(
    function (
        $retries,
        RequestInterface $request,
        ResponseInterface $response = null,
        RequestException $exception = null
    ) {
        // Don't retry if we have run out of retries.
        if ($retries >= 5) {
            return false;
        }

        $shouldRetry = false;
        // Retry connection exceptions.
        if ($exception instanceof ConnectException) {
            $shouldRetry = true;
        }
        if ($response) {
            // Retry on server errors.
            if ($response->getStatusCode() >= 500) {
                $shouldRetry = true;
            }
        }

        // Log if we are retrying.
        if ($shouldRetry) {
            $this->logger->debug(
                sprintf(
                    'Retrying %s %s %s/5, %s',
                    $request->getMethod(),
                    $request->getUri(),
                    $retries + 1,
                    $response ? 'status code: ' . $response->getStatusCode() :
                        $exception->getMessage()
                )
            );
        }

        return $shouldRetry;
    }
));

$client = new Client([
    'handler' => $stack,
    'connect_timeout' => 60.0, // Seconds.
    'timeout' => 1800.0, // Seconds.
]);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm now getting:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 4096

Message: Argument 3 passed to mycontroller::{closure}() must be an instance of ResponseInterface, instance of GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response given

Filename: controllers/mycontroller.php

Line Number: 72

Any ideas?

Comment: Just import the interface.

I didn't include `use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ResponseInterface` because it only a small snippet, not a whole PHP file :)