# Best practice to verify guzzle response

Tags: php, rest, symfony, http, guzzle

I was wondering what is the best practice to check if the guzzle response is ok and avoid blocking the application. I use PHP/Symfony and what I do each time I do a call is the following:

```
try {

    $response = $this->getClient()->request('GET', '/api/rest/contact/' . $email);

} catch (\Exception $e) {

    $logger = $this->get('monolog.logger.myapp');
    $logger->critical('New exception caught while getting user: ' . $e);
    throw new HttpException(406, "Error while getting user.");
}

if(isset($response) && $response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
    return $response->getBody()->getContents();
}

// if it's not 200 or the response is not set, I send a JsonResponse or a flash message to be used in a form for instance:

$this->addFlash('error', $this->get('translator')->trans('form.subscribe.fail', array(), 'messages'));

// or

return new JsonResponse(array('messages' => [0 => $this->get('translator')->trans('form.subscribe.fail', array(), 'messages')]), 400);
```

EDIT to adapt to the answer received:

```
try {

    $response = $this->getClient()->request('GET', '/api/rest/contact/' . $email);

} catch (\Exception $e) {

    $logger = $this->get('monolog.logger.myapp');
    $logger->critical('New exception caught while getting user: ' . $e);

    // the response is not 200 so I send a JsonResponse or a flash message to be used in a form for instance:

    $this->addFlash('error', $this->get('translator')->trans('form.subscribe.fail', array(), 'messages'));

    // or

    return new JsonResponse(array('messages' => [0 => $this->get('translator')->trans('form.subscribe.fail', array(), 'messages')]), 400);
}

return $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"OK" depends on your endpoints' provider. Some providers can response with an error even when status code = 200 (some crapy APIs do this).

Basically, Guzzle by default throws an exception if status code signals about an error (status code >= 400). So you don't need to do additional checks, only handle the exceptions.

BTW, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38622219/322079) for more information.

Comment: thanks for the link! Very interesting the retry function. I edited my code to adapt to your answer. So I can consider that if no exception was caught the response was 200 and I can continue getting the details of the response. However, I'm actually working with a "crappy" API as you said. It returns an error even if the response is 200. In this case my verification is necessary.